# open source tool to create mock up for IOS application

Tags: ios, open-source, mockup-tool

Can somebody suggest me any open source tools to create IOS application mock up screens ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a pretty exhaustive list of both commercial and non-commercial tools here:
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuiPrototypingTools

Answer (score 4):

Try this one https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imockapp/id588325430?ls=1&mt=8. No open-source but it's free and has no ads

Answer (score 2):

Xcode (not opensource - but free!) comes with this built in, very easy to design your interface in the storyboard/xib editor

Comment: thanks for reply..but i think it's for MAC only ? right ? is there any tool for windows 7 ?

Comment: Yes Mac only unfortunately - but it is made for the job

Comment: Nevertheless, Xcode does not really help you designing an app. It's absolutely overkill and you'll definitely have to write code to make a design look like you'd probably want.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 5 / iPhone 4S PSD:**

http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/ios-5-gui-psd-iphone-4s/

**iPad Retina PSD:**

http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/ipad-gui-psd-retina-display/

Comment: Photoshop not exactly open source thou ;)

Comment: There's enough free alternatives: http://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-open-psd-extension-files-without-installing-adobe-photoshop/